# How can I reuse a ViewGroup defined in an XML file multiple times in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create a simple game. I would like to populate a LinearLayout which I have defined in an XML with several RelativeLayouts. Each time the user presses a button I would like a child View to be added to the LinearLayout. Each RelativeLayout would change slightly based on the users input (which buttons were pressed, etc).

I essentially want to create a new RelativeLayout based on an XML layout file. I then want to manipulate some attributes of the RelativeLayout's child Views (specifically the src of some ImageViews) and add it to a LinearLayout. This in itself is not particularly difficult. I can get at each of the RelativeLayout's children using findViewById but I start having problems when I want to create n number of RelativeLayouts based on the same XML. I'm pretty sure duplicate IDs are causing crashes. Can a RelativeLayout work without using IDs? Should I try and find a different way of constructing the interface using different ViewGroups?

I'm not sure if what I am asking is even possible but I know that creating these items on-the-fly using the code alternative to the XML layouts is a horrible thought.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I lost my train of thought halfway through, the previous example had some bugginess. I've updated.

pedr0 has the right idea, but to clarify, you could try something to this effect (assuming you have a RelativeLayout defined in relative.xml). This isn't tested, but the general idea should be valid. You don't even have to do a separate method, you can do it inline in a click handler, or whatever, but I just did the addChildView method for the sake of example:

```
LayoutInflater inflater;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //get the LinearLayout that you plan to add rows to
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);

    //get the LayoutInflater from the system
    inflater = getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    //call getNewChildView with whatever drawable id you want to place
    //as the source. If you want to pass in other types, just change
    //the parameters (e.g. Drawable, Bitmap)
    linearLayout.addView(getNewChildView(R.drawable.my_image));
}

public RelativeLayout getNewChildView(int resId) {
    //inflates a copy of your RelativeLayout template
    RelativeLayout rl =  (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.relative, null);

    //this assumes an ImageView in your RelativeLayout with an id of image
    ImageView img = (ImageView)rl.findViewById(R.id.image);
    img.setBackgroundResource(resId);

    return rl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you both for your quick responses. I had something very similar in mind and in fact was on a similar track and using the LayoutInflator.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I couldn't even work out how to use the code tags properly *sigh*

Thank you both for your quick responses. I had something very similar in mind and in fact was on the same track and using the LayoutInflator. I simplified your example a little as I do not need to pass the id of a drawable around.

```
LayoutInflater inflater;

private void drawGuess() {
    // The top level LinearLayout to add to
    LinearLayout topLevel = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.guessList);

    // get the inflater`
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    // add the view (based on stored data elsewhere)
    topLevel.addView(getLatestGuess());
}

private RelativeLayout getLatestGuess() {
    //inflates a copy of your RelativeLayout template
    RelativeLayout rl =  (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.guess_layout, null);

    //this assumes an ImageView in your RelativeLayout with an id of image
    ImageView guessOne = (ImageView)rl.findViewById(R.id.guess1);
    guessOne.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
}
```

Running this code works, the catch is it only works the first time you call it. The second time you call getLatestGuess() it crashes. Removing the IDs in the XML (e.g. guess1) from all the child views of the RelativeLayout results in no more crashing. Unfortunately now I have a fairly useless RelativeLayout that I can no longer get at the child views of as they do not have IDs. Presumably, IDs are required to be unique.

Comment: Maybe you just left it out, but you're not returning anything in your getLatestGuess method. You should also initialize your inflater in your onCreate() method. What do you mean by it "Crashes"? Check LogCat to find out what's going wrong.

Comment: Sorry, that was a copy/paste mistake on my part. I found a more elegant way to solve this problem was to extend LinearLayout. Relative layout is great when you are using an XML defined layout where every item has it's own ID but for my needs a LinearLayout was more appropriate anyway. Thanks for all your help.

On a side-note, messing around with the LayoutInflater was producing some strange results. Heights and Widths of Layouts were being lost, is this expected behavior?

Comment: Extending LinearLayout seems like it would really be overkill for this situation, but if it works for you then I guess that's great. By "messing around" with the LayoutInflater, can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create an root element, and then add the new child.

Like this:

RelatoveLayout root = ....;

RelativeLayout toadd = inflate(your XML);

apply by code  change depending of users input, for example:

toadd.setBackgroundResource(....);

and finally add the result to the root :

root.addView(toadd).

I really hope to help you!

Bye!